# Is there a Unix command to quote input lines?

Tags: bash, shell, command, xargs

I am wondering if there is a filter command to quote input lines.

So when piping:

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
```

to it, you get:

```
"line number 1"
"line number 2"
"line number 3"
```

I need this command to pipe a stream of lines to `xargs` to make sure that `xargs` treats `line number 1` as one argument and not as three. I am sure that it has many other uses too.

Is there such a command? What is it called?

Comment: Consider also `xargs -0`, which delimits the values with the `NUL` character. The input program will need to know how to do that, though (e.g. `find -print0` and so forth).

Comment: @thrig: `xargs -d '\n'` might be even more useful here, if the OP is using [GNU xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html). (Neither the `-0` nor the `-d` option is [standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html), so they're both potentially non-portable. [BSD xargs](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/xargs.1) does seem to support `-0` but not `-d`, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd offer Perl's `quotemeta` function. Not *quite* what you asked, because it escapes spaces rather than replacing them with quotes.

But as a fringe benefit, it also handles *other* special characters (like `*`):

```
perl -nle 'print quotemeta'
```

(Or as noted in the comments, the shorter form: `perl -ple '$_=quotemeta'`)

Which takes your lines and turns them into:

```
line\ number\ 1
line\ number\ 2
line\ number\ 3
```

Which should have the same result - as well as handling:

```
Line number \"`rm -rf *`\"
```

And similar such shenanigans :)

Comment: `perl -pe '$_=quotemeta'` is shorter.

Comment: @cuonglm: You do want `-ple`, not just `-pe`; without the `-l` switch, it'll also escape the line feed. And if you wish to golf it, `perl -ple '$_="\Q$_"'` (or even `perl -pe 's/.*/\Q$&/'`) is shorter yet. :-)

Comment: Note that it breaks multi-byte character sequences which with some `xargs` implementations will cause problem. For instance, in a UTF-8 locale on Solaris, `echo Stéphane | perl -lpe '$_=quotemeta' | xargs printf '<%s>\n'` fails with `xargs: Corrupt input file: Illegal byte sequence`.

Comment: And if you add the `-C` option to `perl`, at least with the 5.12.5 on Solaris, it fails to quote all the characters that are considered as separator by `xargs` (for instance U+2006). `printf 'a\u2006b\n' | perl -C -lpe '$_=quotemeta' | xargs printf '<%s>\n'` outputs `<a>` and `<b>` on Solaris.

Answer (score 9):

Not one specifically designed for it but many multi-purpose tools can do this:

- `sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'`
- `perl -pe 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'` or `perl -lne 'print "\"$_\""'`
- `awk '{printf "\"%s\"\n",$0}'`
- `while read -r line; do printf '"%s"\n' "$line"; done`

(All of these assume that the line doesn't contain a double quote. If it does, it will break `xargs`)

Answer (score 4):

If on a GNU system, look into the `--delimiter` argument to `xargs`. Since your input is separated by newlines, you needn't rely on quoting at all, or use any additional tools:

```
cat files.txt | xargs --delimiter=\\n printf "<%s>"
```

Where `files.txt` contains your input:

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
```

Gives the output:

```
<line number 1><line number 2><line number 3>
```

NB: You do not need to store your input in a file and use `cat`; you may of course pipe directly from another program. I used `cat` in my example due to its ubiquity and utility in creating self-contained examples such as this.

Even better (and recommended by the `xargs` manual) is to have your output program separate the entries by the NUL (`\0`) instead of a newline, and use the `--null` option instead of `--delimiter`, but as long as your input strings will never themselves contain newlines, you're OK with the above approach.

Comment: The regex answers were a bit of a give away. The OP was really in search of delimeters.

Answer (score 3):

On GNU system, with shell support `$'...'`:

```
xargs -d$'\n' printf '%s\n' <<\IN            
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
IN
```

With standard tools:

```
:|paste -d'"' - file - | xargs printf '%s\n'
```

Both of these assumed that your line didn't contain embedded quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you'd need to add a `"` at the beginning and end *and* transform the `"`s into `"\""`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'foo "bar" baz' 'biz' |
  sed 's/"/"\\""/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' |
  xargs printf '<%s>\n'
```

outputs:

```
<foo "bar" baz>
<biz>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{ echo "x1 x2 x3" ; echo "y1 y2 y3"; } | xargs -L1 echo

x1 x2 x3
y1 y2 y3
```

The `-L1` will use each line separately

However the manpage is spoiling it:

> A line ending with a space continues to the next non-empty line.

See here:

```
{ echo "x1 x2 x3 " ; echo "y1 y2 y3"; } | xargs -L1 echo

x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
```